# Is JSDoc supported by sonarqube?

Tags: javascript, documentation, sonarqube, jsdoc

Can Sonarqube take into account JSdoc from Javascript files ?

We have many javascript source files analyzed by Sonarqube but the "Documentation" metric remains at 0.

The "comment" metric shows the right value but it's not the case for the Documentation metric.

Answer (score 0):

According to [thread from 2012](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/JSDoc-example-usage-code-is-detected-as-quot-Commented-Code-quot-td5003097.html) it should be available. However that link is dead.

The sonar issues [SONARS-46](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-46) and [SONARJS-182](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-182) tell us that JSDocs from JavaScript are analyzed by SonarQube, but may still be a bit buggy.

There are a [bunch of bugs](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-452?jql=project%20%3D%20SONARJS%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) referring to comment-handling that are currently being worked on and should go live with 2.8 of [sonarjs](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS/?).

Comment: here you are talking about the rule that detects commented-out code. But from my understanding the question is about the metric that gives the percentage of documented code.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed documentation metric is not supported for JavaScript project because
documentation is a percentage which is calculated from:

- the number of documented Public API element
- the number of undocumented Public API element

So the question is what a Public API element ? In Java for example it is pretty straight forward, e.g: for a class every public methods will be Public API and private methods are not.

But in the case of JavaScript there is no strict way to determine what is Public API from and what is not. This information is required because we need a value of comparison, e.g: for commented line we have uncommented line and from those 2 values we calculate Comment percentage value.

I hope this was clear and helpful and if you have any suggestion on how to identify Public API in JavaScript you are very welcome!